# Correct way to return from inside of for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have this little method which takes an integer argument and checks if an array (which is set as an attribute) contains a certain object. If it does, it returns that object, otherwise it returns `null`. The problem here is that I get an error when I try to return something. Here it is:

```
myClass.java:33: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
1 error
```

I do have a return statement and it includes the ternary operator, meaning that it returns something at any cost. Here's my method:

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        return (listaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) ? listaBanesave[i] : null;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it? Why do I get that error?

Comment: What will your method return if `listaBanesave.length` is `0`?

Comment: put return statement after for...loop also.

Comment: If the `for` loop is not entered, your method does not return.

Comment: move the return statement outside the for loop

Comment: I think you should write your code in a clearer fashion, avoiding the `?:` operator in this case. this is definitely an opinion but I don't think you'd have hit this problem if you'd declared a var to hold the return value and assigned it if found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> takes an integer argument and checks if an array (which is set as an attribute) contains a certain object. If it does, it returns that object, otherwise it returns null.

Given your requirements, your code should be (for example):

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {
    Banesa ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        ret = listaBansesave[i];
        if (ret.getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses)
            return ret;
    }

    // No element found or list is empty
    return null;
}
```

With your current code:

- if the list is empty, the "for" loop is not entered and therefore there is no return statement -- hence your compile error;
- in any case you only ever check for the first element, you *never* check the others, since you `return` in each iteration (of which there will only be one)

Comment: This is the best code until now. However, when I put 0 to check via this method, it returns a `NullPointerException`. What could this be?

Comment: Where? If in the `for` loop it means your array has null elements in it; you didn't mention that in the question ;)

Comment: Lets say index 1, 2 and 3 of the array are filled, but the rest are not. When for example I put 0 or 4 (or any other number beside these) I get that exception.

Comment: Fixed by changing the if to this: `if (ret != null && ret.getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) {`...

Comment: Triple comment, but wanted to say Thank you :).

Comment: You could also `break` out of the loop if `ret == null`, but why don't you use a `List` instead?

Comment: Yeah I'm always for a `List` and `ArrayList` instead, but we have to move on "gradually" is what they're saying -_-. I keep telling them that normal arrays are not so good anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `return` outside the loop. Because when `listaBanesave` is empty, there won't be a `return` statement - That what makes the compiler angry.

What to `return` is your decision.. Depends on your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong too. You only check if the first item in the array is == the int you passed to the function. After checking the first item there is definitely a return doesn't matter which case is true (if or else) and the function ends. It is the same like:

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {

    return (listaBanesave[0].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) ? listaBanesave[i] : null;

}
```

it should be:

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) 
    {
        if(istaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses)     
            return listaBanesave[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: While you do make the correct point, I'm convinced an inexperienced programmer won't be able to understand how you got there. Why is it only checking the first item?

Comment: I like this but still prefer to keep the return out the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should return null as the last line of the method, even according to your specification ("If it does, it returns that object, **otherwise it returns null**.").

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        return (listaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) ? listaBanesave[i] : null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the condition in loop doesn't satisfy and no returning might happen.

So you need to have a default return.

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        return (listaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) ? listaBanesave[i] : null;
    }
   return null; //when there is no chance to enter in loop.
}
```

Comment: Good design says that there should be only one entry point and only one exit point. So A return value should be stored and this value should be returned. It is preferable to have only one return in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop over *all* items in `listaBanesave` and check if *each* meets the criteria and, if none of them do, `return null`. Currently your code returns `null` if the *first* item does not meet the criteria - i.e. it could be rewritten as:

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {
    if(listaBanesave.length == 0)
        return null;
    return (listaBanesave[0].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) ? listaBanesave[0] : null;
}
```

Presumably this isn't what you want.

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        if (listaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) {
            return listaBanesave[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So check each item in the loop; it if matches, return it. Otherwise, once the loop is finished, you know you have no match - the `return null`.

Answer (score 0):

In line with my comment, I'd prefer this to be written:

```
public Banesa gjejBanese(int nrBaneses) {
    Banesa found = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listaBanesave.length; i++) {
        if (listaBanesave[i].getNrBanesa() == nrBaneses) {   // should this be == or equals()?
            found = listaBanesave[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

I just think it's clearer, there's one point of exit (rather than in a for loop). I'd say the `?:` operator is very useful but that it doesn't assist readability in your scenario.

Also, I've left a comment to check if "==" is a sufficient test or should `#equals be user?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't picture a variable called `found` to be anything other than a `boolean`.

Comment: Fair point, I started the post deciding between returnValue, banesa and then probably just posted before properly thinking through. The general gist of what I'm saying is there though.